# Rendering problems with default Android Studio project

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-studio-2.0

I've been working with Android Studio for a bit now, learning how to develop apps. I've noticed that when I make a project, starting with a blank activity, it gives me rendering errors right from the start. Rarely am I ever able to actually see a preview of my XML layout in Android Studio. It seems like the default project starts off with a Coordinator Layout and that Android Studio has issues with that. Is there any way to correct this? Below is a screenshot of what I'm seeing.

[image]

This is only after creating a new project and adding a couple very basic elements to my XML layout. This was happening with Android Studio 1.5, and the 2.0 preview.

Comment: update your android sdk

Answer (score 2):

In the design tab you will see a little android guy with a '23' next to it. Click the drop down and select a different sdk. OR  make sure you have the SDK version that is selected.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes rendering problems occur with project, 
This can does because of high version not supported in android studio.
Change lollipop to Jelly bean or ice cream sandwich.